# How do I clear a mocked playwright response?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, playwright

Per [playwright documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/network#api-reference-2) you can mock an API call

This works fine for me but I have two tests that have different mock responses in the same file.

```
submitMock = (response) => page.route(/submit/, (route) =>
    route.fulfill({
      status: status || 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(response),
    }),
  );

/// my test code
describe('fill form', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    jest.resetAllMocks(); // doesn't clear mock requests
    await setupAppMocks(); // some basic mocks
    await page.goto(
      `${localhost}/?foo=bar`,
    );
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await browser.close();
  });

  it('should test scenario 1', async () => {
    expect.hasAssertions();

    const responseMock = { test: 'test' };
    await submitMock(responseMock); // first mock created here

    await fillForm();
    await clickSubmit();

    await page.waitForSelector('[class*="CongratulationsText"]');

    const sectionText = await page.$eval(
      '[class*="CongratulationsText"]',
      (e) => e.textContent,
    );

    expect(sectionText).toBe(
      `Congratulations, expecting message for scenario 1`,
    );
  });

  it('should test scenario 2', async () => {
    expect.hasAssertions();

    const responseMock = { test: 'test 2' };
    await submitMock(responseMock); // second mock created here

    await fillForm();
    await clickSubmit();

    await page.waitForSelector('[class*="CongratulationsText"]');

    const sectionText = await page.$eval(
      '[class*="CongratulationsText"]',
      (e) => e.textContent,
    );

    // fails because first mock is still active
    expect(sectionText).toBe(
      `Congratulations, expecting message for scenario 2`,
    );
  });
});
```

Is there a way to clear the previous mock?

What I've tried so far is basically adding another mock but it doesn't seem to override the previous one. I'm assuming that the issue is that the mocks for the same pattern can't be overridden, but I don't have an easy way to fix the issue.

Comment: You can unroute your routes.

Comment: @hardkoded, could you explain how?

Comment: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#pageunrouteurl-handler found this I guess

Comment: Thanks @hardkoded for the suggestion, it worked

Answer (score 4):

The way to unmock an API call is to use `page.unroute` [Documentation here](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#pageunrouteurl-handler)

```
page.unroute(/submit/);
```